# $(document).keydown/up not working when using a secondary key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this code

```
$(document).keydown(function(){ 
   $("#movecheck").text("true");
   isMoving = true;
}); 
$(document).keyup(function(){ 
   $("#movecheck").text("false");
   isMoving = false;
});
```

currently when using 1 key at a time it works fine, but when using 2 keys, where one would be held and the other not, `isMoving` returns false when the second key is no longer being pressed, whilst the first key is still down, i have an anti-ghosting keyboard so i know this cant be the problem, so i believe it might have something to do with how jquery checks if a key is down.

how could i make it work using multiple keys?

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use an integer instead of a boolean because currently, `isMoving` will always be set to `false` when you release a key no matter how many other keys are still pressed.

Here is an example using an integer variable:

```js
let pressedCount = 0;
$(document).keydown(function(event){
   if (!event.originalEvent.repeat) {
     pressedCount++;
     setMoveCheck();
   }
});
$(document).keyup(function(){
   pressedCount--;
   setMoveCheck();
}); 

function isMoving() {
  return pressedCount !== 0;
}

function setMoveCheck() {
  $("#movecheck").text(isMoving() ? "true" : "false");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="movecheck">false</div>
```

Beside that, you'll also have to check if the `keydown` event is generated because a key is kept pressed.

Comment: thats good, but occasionally i run into an error where `isMoving()` returns true despite no keys whatsoever being down, how could i fix that?

Comment: @Chaps I've edited my answer to add a check for repeated key down events. If you've tested using that check and this still fails, I'm not sure what could be the problem.

Comment: ive encountered another issue, where in using multiple keys, and switching, occasionally pressedCount becomes 1 and does not go down, resulting; in my case: infinite unstoppable movement. how could this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let activeCount = 0

function checkStatus() {
  if (activeCount) {
    $("#movecheck").text("true");
  } else {
    $("#movecheck").text("false");
  }
}

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  activeCount++;
  checkStatus()
});
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  --activeCount;
  checkStatus()
});

checkStatus()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='movecheck'></div>
```